# Ruby on Rails - How to let non signed in user to leave message on my post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

**I have post model**

On my post_controller

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
```

So guest(non signed in user) can see my post.

My Question is

> How to let guest(non signed in user) leave a message inside my post ?

**For Example:**
Let say Message model has these params :

```
name:string
phone:string
email:String
text:text
```

And in message view i want something like this :

```
<div>
<%= name %>
<%= phone %>
<%= email %>
<%= text %>
</div>
```

Any Advice? thx for helping !

Comment: what issue are you facing with, it can be done with form to let user submit their message.? can you explain your doubt?

Comment: I tried by my self but when i clicked submit button to create message,it rendered :new bcoz it failed

Comment: Did u try the given solution below? And just use debugger after save and check why does it rollback for create message.?

Comment: Not yet. Im still outside. I will try later. Thx for ur advice sir

Comment: Sure let me know for any further guidance.

Comment: it worked sir.. one more question.. how i can render those params on my post view? i tried <% @messages.each do |m| %> <%= m.name %> but it render all messages from all my posts(i have message on my each post)

Comment: Did you noticed that i have added `post_id` in message and also belongs_to in message, you have to do one thing is that write has_many in post model as `has_many: messages` here you will be able to get all messages for that post just define in `posts#show` @post.messages which will return all the messages for that post and you can make it dynamic at view page. also feel free to upvote/accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: Everything works Great now. thx you very much for helping me again sir :)

Comment: Glad to know that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- If message is for post then Message model should have `post_id`

messages.rb

```
belongs_to :post
```

2- At `posts#show` action define new `message`

```
@message = Message.new
```

3 - At below your each post there should be a form for message

```
<%= form_for @message do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field: name %>
  <%= f.email_field: email %>
  <%= f.text_field: phone %>
  <%= f.text_area: text %>
  <%= f.hidden_field: post_id, value: @post.id %>
  <%= f.submit: "Submit Message"%>
<% end %>
```

4 - In `messages_controller.rb`

```
before_action :authetnicate_user!, only: []

def create
  message = Message.new(message_params)
  if message.save
    #
  else
   #
  end
end
 private
 def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name,:email,:phone,:text,:post_id,)
 end
```

Comment: message form probably needs different handling for when user IS logged in, but hey, it's not our job to write the full app :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yep agree :)